# ERROR MOUNT : XAMPP htdocs MacOS High Sierra

Tags: php, xampp

I'm starting in PHP, install XAMPP in my MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5 to make my first hello world, I set out to find the htdocs folder as it is in windows.
In MacOS to explore I have to press "Mount" and "Explore" to htdocs as shown in the image.

[image]

But every time I press "Mount" my macbook restarts.

Please help.